# KafkaStreams serde exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

i am playing with Kafka and streams technology; i have created a custom serializer and deserializer for the KStream that i will use to receive messages from a given topic.

Now, the problem is that i am creating a serde in this way:

```
JsonSerializer<EventMessage> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>();
JsonDeserializer<EventMessage> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(EventMessage.class);
Serde<EventMessage> messageSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer);
```

Serializer implementation:

```
public class JsonSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        return gson.toJson(data).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

Deserializer implementation:

```
public class JsonDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Class<T> deserializedClass;

    public JsonDeserializer() {

    }

    public JsonDeserializer(Class<T> deserializedClass) {
        this.deserializedClass = deserializedClass;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
        if(deserializedClass == null) {
            deserializedClass = (Class<T>) map.get("serializedClass");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        System.out.print(data);
        if(data == null){
            return null;
        }

        return gson.fromJson(new String(data),deserializedClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

When i try to execute the code, i receive the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$WrapperSerde Does it have a public no-argument constructor?

Full dump here: https://pastebin.com/WwpuXuxB

This is the way i am trying to use serde:

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, EventMessage> eventsStream = builder.stream(stringSerde, messageSerde, topic);

KStream<String, EventMessage> outStream = eventsStream
            .mapValues(value -> EventMessage.build(value.type, value.timestamp));

outStream.to("output");
```

Also, i am not totally sure i am setting up correctly the properties to setup up serializer and deserializer globally:

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, messageSerde.getClass());
```

Comment: Can you check whether adding an explicit default (non-argument) constructor to `JsonSerializer` would help?

Comment: `StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass()` should be `StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName()`, for example.

Answer (score 8):

To complete the Matthias answer I've just coded a simple example of how to create a custom Serde (Serializer / Deserializer) within a Kafka Stream App. It's is available to clone and try in: https://github.com/Davidcorral94/Kafka-Streams-Custom-Seder

First I create two classes, one for the Serializer and another for the Deserializer. In this case I use [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) to perform the serialization/deserialization.

### Serializer

```
public class PersonSerializer implements Closeable, AutoCloseable, Serializer<Person> {

    private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    static private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String s, Person person) {
        // Transform the Person object to String
        String line = gson.toJson(person);
        // Return the bytes from the String 'line'
        return line.getBytes(CHARSET);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

### Deserializer

```
public class PersonDeserializer implements Closeable, AutoCloseable, Deserializer<Person> {

    private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    static private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
    }

    @Override
    public Person deserialize(String topic, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            // Transform the bytes to String
            String person = new String(bytes, CHARSET);
            // Return the Person object created from the String 'person'
            return gson.fromJson(person, Person.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error reading bytes", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

Then, I wrap both of them into a Serde to be able to use it into my Kafka Stream App.

### Serde

```
public class PersonSerde implements Serde<Person> {
    private PersonSerializer serializer = new PersonSerializer();
    private PersonDeserializer deserializer = new PersonDeserializer();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        serializer.configure(configs, isKey);
        deserializer.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        serializer.close();
        deserializer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Serializer<Person> serializer() {
        return serializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Deserializer<Person> deserializer() {
        return deserializer;
    }
}
```

Finally, you are able to use this Serde class into your Kafka Stream App with the next line:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, PersonSerde.class);
```

This is actually working with the latest Kafka version available at this moment which is 1.0.0!

Answer (score 3):

If you call `Serdes.serdeFrom(...)` you get a `WrappedSerde` type back that is for internal usage (and `WrappedSerde` does not have an non-argument constructor). There is currently no API you can call to get a custom `Serde`. Instead, you need to implement you own `Serde` class and wrap you serializer and deserializer "manually".

```
public class EventMessageSerde implements Serde<EventMessage> {
    final private JsonSerializer<EventMessage> serializer;
    final private JsonDeserializer<EventMessage> deserializer;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        serializer.configure(configs, isKey);
        deserializer.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        serializer.close();
        deserializer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Serializer<EventMessage> serializer() {
        return serializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Deserializer<EventMessage> deserializer() {
        return deserializer;
    }
}
```

In your `Properties` you can set:

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, EventMessageSerde.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, i'll try asap and give you feedback !

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using `StreamsBuilder` instead of `KStreamBuilder`. `KStreamBuilder` is deprecated in 1.0.0. You can directly pass serde object using `Consumed.with` while creating stream. You need not to create custom `Serde` class in this scenario.

```
Serde<EventMessage> messageSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer);

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, EventMessage> eventsStream = builder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), messageSerde));
```

You can keep `StringSerde` in below code instead of using `messageSerde.getClass()` which is failing because `messageSerde` is just a `WrappedSerde` that does not have non-argument constructor.

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerde.class.getName());
```