# KafkaStream does not use the serde given in Consumed.with(), but uses the default serde

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have created Serde consuming from kafka as the following

```java
import org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer;

final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
final Serde<JsonNode> jsonNodeSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);

final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

final KStream<String, JsonNode> eventStream = builder
                .stream("my-test-1",
                        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonNodeSerde)
```

but still receive serialization error:

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.`

As `Consumed.with()` is already provided, why the default serde is still used? As the answer written here, this should work, or?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832957/3952994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that your data doesn't match the serdes.

```
A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer /
              value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer)
is not compatible to the actual key or value type
             (key type: java.lang.String /
              value type: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode).
```

However, the error message says the problem is caused when data is *serialized*, i.e. when Kafka Streams attempts to *write* the data somewhere.

Your code snippet with `Consumed`, however, is about *deserializing* and thus *reading* data. Therefore it seems that the problem is not caused by the code snippet you shared in your question, but by code that is presumably further down in your Java file, which is not shown in your question. (Btw, it would have helped if you had provided the full stack trace of the error.)